# Как поставить запятую и два нуля после нее?

Tags: java

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {

        float[] numbers = {331.54f, 762.47f, 194.78f, 865.21f, 629.45f, 594.47f, 192.63f, 435.14f, 150.41f, 575.74f};
        float len = numbers.length;

        sort(numbers);

        for (float i = 0; i < len; i++)
            System.out.printf("%.2f%n", numbers[i]);
    }

    public static void sort(float[] numbers) {

        float len = numbers.length;
        float temp;

        for (float i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            for (int j = 1; j < (len - i); j++) {

                if (numbers[j - 1] > numbers[j]) {

                    temp = numbers[j - 1];
                    numbers[j - 1] = numbers[j];
                    numbers[j] = temp;

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

```java
for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    System.out.printf(Locale.forLanguageTag("RU"), "%.2f%n", numbers[i]);
}
```